# Bound on ratio of sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, sums-of-squares

I would am interested in upper (or lower) bounds of the following ratio:

$$\frac{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j^2}{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j b_j}$$

where $a_j$ are non-negative integers, and $b_j$ are non-negative reals. As far as the numerator, I could bound using some simple options like $$\sum_{j=1}^k a_j^2\leq(\max_j a_j)^2 \cdot k$$ or via Holder $$\sum_{j=1}^k a_j^2\leq(\max_j a_j)\sum_{j=1}^k a_j$$ or even some rudimentary bound like if I assume $\sum_{j=1}^k a_j=C$, then $$\sum_{j=1}^k a_j^2\leq C\sqrt{C}.$$

Is there any obvious bound that I am over looking? If we further assume that $\sum_{j=1}^k b_j=L$, then we could write
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j^2}{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j b_j}\leq&\frac{C\sqrt{C}}{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j b_j} \\
\leq& \frac{C\sqrt{C}}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j^2} \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k b_j^2}}\\
\leq& \frac{C\sqrt{C}}{\sqrt{C\sqrt{C}}\sqrt{L\sqrt{L}}}=\frac{C^\frac{3}{4}}{L^\frac{3}{2}}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $A=(a_1,a_2,\cdots a_n)$ and $B=(b_1,b_2,\cdots b_n)$ as $n$ dimensional vectors.

Your expression can be written as the square of a norm divided by a dot product:

$$R=\|A\|^2/(A \cdot B)=\|A\|^2/(\|A\|\|B\| \cos \alpha)=\|A\|/(\|B\| \cos \alpha)$$

where the cosine is positive due to the positivity of the coordinates.

Therefore the minimal value of $R$ is

$$\|A\|/\|B\|=\sqrt{\sum a_i^2/\sum b_i^2 }$$

knowing that its maximal value can be arbitrarily large.

Remark: the fact that the $a_i$ are integers and the $b_i$ are real doesn't play any role.

Comment: Thank you @ Jean Marie! That is very helpful. Does the upper bound I wrote above look correct / as sharp as can easily found to you?

Comment: If the $a_i$ are bounded by a universal bound $C$, the numerator of $\|A\|/\|B\|=\sqrt{\sum a_i^2/\sum b_i^2 }$ can be bounded by $C \sqrt{n}$, **but** the cosine in the denominator can be arbitrarily close to zero, still giving an arbitrarily large ratio.

Comment: could you add some explanation as to what $\cos(\alpha)$ is and why it equals 1 when $R$ is minimized?

Comment: Concerning bounds; you have made an error by writing (s an application of Cauchy Schwarz inequality) : $\frac{C\sqrt{C}}{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j b_j}
\color{red}{\leq} \frac{C\sqrt{C}}{\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j^2} \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k b_j^2}}$ : the inequality should be reversed

Comment: When you say the $a_i$ are bounded, do you mean $\sum a_i<\infty$ or $\max a_i <\infty$?

Comment: The only element on which we can play is $0 \le \cos \alpha \le 1$...

Comment: Thank you so much @Jean Marie. You are right about the CS inequality being wrong. Is there any other bound you can think of to simplify and get a nice upper bound for the expression?

Comment: It depends very much on your data... The ideal, if you can, is to have coefficients $a_i$ "approximatively" proportional to coefficients $b_i$ in order that $\cos \alpha$ is close to $1$.

Comment: So am I correct in assuming that if $a_j\propto b_j$ i.e. $a_j=\beta b_j$ for some $\beta\in \mathbb{R}$ then my original ratio of sums is maximized with a value of $\frac{||A||}{||B||}$ and the larger $|a_j-\beta b_j|$ becomes for some optimal $\beta$, my original ratio of sums goes to 0?

Comment: OK that makes sense, so I can think of it like as the "correlation coef" gets smaller (as in as $a_j$ gets "less proportional'' to $b_j$) then $\frac{||A||}{||B||\cos(\alpha)}$ increases in value.   But so as you see it, I can't really write something more clever than $$\frac{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j^2}{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j b_j}\leq\frac{C\sqrt{C}}{\sum_{j=1}^k a_j b_j}$$ as far as upper bounds go?

Comment: Not really maximized because your $\cos α$ will be maybe 0.95 (think to its close statistical cousin : correlation coefficient): therefore consider that the quotient of norms is still a minimum but that you are slightly above that.

Comment: Is this upper bound in the RHS really useful for you, as long as the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are still present in it ?

Comment: No it is not, you are right. But ultimately, the problem I am trying to solve needs to have some upper bound in terms of $\sum a_i=C$ and $\sum b_i=L$ because I know what $C$ and $L$ are... perhaps I am trying to force things and need to take a different approach.